# Through java APIs can i call C function

Tags: java

I having a embedded Hardware and all driver of this hardware written in C and my application program written in java.So,how can i interface with with my java application and C lang ptogramming.

Comment: Are you Looking for JNI ?https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use
[Java Native Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can call a C funtion via java through JNI ,below are the steps with example

Suppose you want to get a string say GetName from c

1)Create a Java Class name JNICallExample

Class JNICallExample{

public native String getname();

}

2)You then compile it and create a class file and then where the class file is located run the command :javah NameOfTheJavafile

3)You will get a generated a .h file (ie:JNICall.h)

4)With the .h file create a C file with the .h file included in it as a header

5)now after the C file is created run the below command

gcc -fPIC -shared -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/linux -o libJNIDemo.so JNICall.c

where /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include is your java home location

6)This will generate a .so file (eg  in above libJNIDemo.so)

7)Now include this in your Java File ,so the above java file will get modify as

Class JNICallExample{

static{

```
    System.loadLibrary("libJNIDemo.so");
}
```

public native String getname();

}